# Remove the .html extension in the URL, when the folder has the same name as the .html file

Tags: .htaccess, url

I have a problem with removing `.html` extensions from the website address. Everything works fine until I create a folder with the name that some file already has in the given location. For example, the situation with such files:

```
index.html
example1.html
example1/example2.html
```

When I try to go from `index.html` to `example1.html`, the page does not read the extension and shows me the folder tree instead of the page. It just goes to the `example1` folder instead of `example1.html`. Anyone can help me? I've tried most (if not all) solutions to this problem with Google and nothing works :( I leave the content of `.htaccess` below. Thanks in advance

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
RewriteEngine on

# REMOVE .HTML
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Try switching off "content negotiation" in your http server: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html

Comment: How can I do this? I read the information at this link, but it did not help me because I am still completely green in it :/ (I have a domain and hosting on OVH, if it matters)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer to this question, just add these lines of code to `.htaccess`.

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.(php|html)[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Hm, to me this looks like you just copied some code you found somewhere without actually understanding what it does... Because this does not really match the description you gave in the question...

Comment: I simply searched for the answer to my problem for a long time and when I found something that worked, I decided to use it. I don't need to understand this code because I don't think it's useful for anything yet. And if you mean that this code also refers to PHP, not just HTML, I just didn't want to remove it, because maybe I will want to remove this extension too :)

Comment: Blindly copying something without understanding what you are doing and what some borrowed code does never is a good idea. You are the boss, but I really recommend investing effort into mastering the tools you are trying to use. You will only frustrate yourself otherwise when strange things happen later which you cannot explain.

Comment: I know that blindly copying is not a good idea and I would never copy anything without understanding the code to e.g. HTML or CSS, but when another person had the same problem as me (only needed php in addition to html), and the language in which the .htaccess file is written does not seem easy, I just prefer to understand the code in general and not waste my time trying to understand it in detail line by line, as I am not going to deal with it in the near future.

Comment: You are the boss :-)